# Android send Log.d to remote IP

Tags: android

I have an Android app that communicate with a server in a Local Area Network using Wifi.
Now I want to redirect all the Log.d() output to this remote server. Is there a automatic way to do that? Or should I implement a UDP socket to transmit this log?

Best regards,